# Tumblr API displaying post text from JSON

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I have created a tumblr blog with two basic text posts to prove a concept...failing at the minute.

Using this example: http://jsfiddle.net/keckclip/9LNDX/5/ and by replacing the api_key and url only I can return the title etc but nothing within the post section of the json.  I understand it's anarray but this is the code I have but it doesn't display anything from the posts.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var API_KEY = "api key goes here";

var tumblrAPI = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blogurlgoesintohere/posts/text?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&callback=?";

$.getJSON(tumblrAPI).done(function (data) {
    $('#blog_title').append(data.response.blog.name);
    $.each(data.response.posts, function (i, item) {
        $("<div>").addClass("post").html(item.text).appendTo("#posts");
    });
});
```

});

Seen quite a few examples but none explicitly explaining the best way to display post data.

My html includes:

```
<div id="blog_title" class="col-md-12"></div>
<div id="blog_post" class="col-md-12"></div>
```

I know, as always, it is likely something obvious but I would appreciate some assistance.

I know there are similar questions out there but I think mine is a different problem, perhaps nobody is as naive as me.

Edit -> the json is correct...

Comment: It's working for me? I see posts in the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah the fiddle works for me until I try my api-key and blog...then I can pull back the info but nothing to do with the posts...baffling me!Both my site and jsfiddle has the same problem - the posts are "text" and I don't think there is any other settings for me to set before I can view the post info

Comment: Do you have Quote posts on your blog? That's the only silly question I can think of that needs to be asked.

Comment: Good point, no I don't but I've already removed that from my site without success :(  I should have said, the JSON does display the posts - the JS is just not doing anything with them (I think)

Comment: Well, I mean, this API call is only going to work for Quote posts because of a) the type included in the URL and b) the fields you're accessing in the callback.

Comment: Ok, but if I read the API correctly  in removing the quote and replacing with text and using the same field..it should work...but it doesn't (ill edit question, thanks)

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not using the right fields. Text posts use `title` and `body` not `text`

Comment: Yup, I see it now - so obvious...I was thinking about the earlier part and not the item.text which should be item.body!  My bad!  Put it an answer and ill tick